# extjs form submit model design

Tags: forms, extjs

I have a form template which contains around 30 kinds of forms. Each time only 1 form will be selected and submitted. The number of elements in the form varies but around 80 or even more.

I have 2 requirements for this:

1. The form submit should be able to cached into the localStorage and resumit to server later when network recover. How can i persistent the forms?
2. I don't want to put the model in the extjs because the model will be constructed at the true backend. And the backend will construct it based on the combination of user selections and inputs. Not sure this make sense or not. The only thing I can think of is to set the inputId by some rules and do the mapping at backend.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you push the base form data into a local object (array?), before submitting, and use $.ajax( ..., data:myDataObject ) to submit the data to the backend instead of the form? This way you'd have the data cached, can repopulate form, or resubmit as you need based on response.

I haven't used extjs (looks nice though), but I imagine something like this:

```
function submitter() {
    var myData = new Object();   //maybe make an array/object to store each form dataset separately?
    //pseudo:
    for each form element {
        myData.push(item = value);
    }
    $.ajax({
        'dataType': 'json',
        'type': 'GET',
        'url': sSource,
        'data': myData,
        'success': [fnCallback, fnMy2ndCallback]  //single or array of callbacks.
    });
    function fnCallback(response) {
        //check for failure, or success and proceed accordingly.
    }
```

Don
have a great day

Comment: I finally use the form.getValues() to retrieve all the dirty fields and store them.

Comment: glad I could help out. and form.getValues() to go through the values and save them sounds good. Did you store each form individually?